# Input and Output Impedance parameters of two port network

Tags: impedance, network, input-impedance, homework

I am reading about two port network and I come to about Z-parametrs

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{V_1}  \\ \mathbf{V_2}  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{Z_{11}} & \mathbf{Z_{12}} \\ \mathbf{Z_{21}} & \mathbf{Z_{22}} \end{bmatrix} .\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{I_1}  \\ \mathbf{I_2}  \end{bmatrix} $$

but then it introduces the concept of input and output impedance which is $$Z_{in} = Z_{11}-\frac{Z_{12}Z_{21}}{Z_{22}+Z_L}$$and also $$Z_{out} = Z_{22}-\frac{Z_{12}Z_{21}}{Z_{11}+Z_S}$$
Where \$Z_L\$ is load impedance and \$Z_S\$ is source impedance. 
I don't know how writer concluded these impedance. Please provide me the explanation.

Comment: Well, ZL is the load impedance, isn't it? I would say, the one connected to port 2, okay? For me, the second equation has something strange... maybe you meant Zsource instead of ZL? I will assume that when you compute Zout, ZL will be connected to port 1 :)

Comment: For the input impedance, expand the matrix equation and then use the output condition: \$Z_L=-\frac{V_2}{I_2}\$. Similar approach for the output impedance.

Comment: @Chu you might want to make that comment an answer, I'd vote it up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the input impedance, expand the matrix equation and then use the output condition: \$Z_L=-\large \frac{V_2}{I_2}\$

Similar approach for the output impedance.

Comment: Can someone show/explain me the expansion please? Thanks a lot!